# How to create an .exe file for my flash application

Tags: flash

I've created a game which will load some data onto the frames from an xml file. Now, I want to create an .exe file for my game which is developed using adobe cs6 so that I need not copy the xml file and swf file every time. Thank you

Comment: What are the extensions of your current files?

Comment: .fla for the file that i've wrote action script and other frames, .swf for the flash that is created and .xml file for the file which contains data

Comment: You can 'hardcode'(type or embed the xmls) into the .swf if you want and then it's a matter of getting an .exe from your swf (either using the standalone flash player to create a project, using a 3rdparty application (like mProjector, zinc,etc.) or publishing an air file)